# chat with SQL DB Tables in Azure OpenAI

Tags: azure-openai

I am trying to develop the chat with SQL DB Tables in Azure OpenAI. I have tried plugins/function calling to call the stored procedure.

It requires recursively asking AOAI to fix the query if the generated statement throws errors.

Comment: Please read [ask] and how to write a [mcve]. As written, there's no detail here (and it's unclear this is a programming question)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [blog](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/analytics-on-azure-blog/revolutionizing-sql-queries-with-azure-open-ai-and-semantic/ba-p/3913513) to start the Revolutionizing SQL Queries with Azure Open AI and Semantic Kernel.
[image]

you can use the Power BI copilot for SQL.

Comment: This isn't an answer. At best, the link should be a comment under the question. But... the OP has shown *no work at all*, just a requirement. There's no programming question, and nothing to answer (plus a link-only answer isn't a valid answer)